# Error when I select date using datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

There is a problem with a React component. Maybe someone khow, what's wrong here. I use the react-datepicker library in my project to fill the date input on the client side. All form inputs work, but an error occurs when I try to select a date in the calendar drop-down menu.

I'm new to react, and maybe there is some kind of error in working with the states.
I would be grateful for any help!

Here is the listing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class Transfer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: [],
      loading: true,
      error: false,
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      people: this.state.people,
      date: this.state.date,
      text: this.state.text
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:5555/email/transfer', { data })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(data);
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">

        <h5>Заказать трансфер</h5>

        <form action="" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="label-section">Имя</div>
          <input name="name" id="name" type="text" defaultValue="" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} /><br />
          <div className="label-section">Email</div>
          <input name="email" id="email" type="text" defaultValue="" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} /><br />
          <div className="label-section">Телефон</div>
          <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" defaultValue="" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} /><br />
          <div className="label-section">Количество человек</div>
          <input name="people" id="people" type="number" min="1" max="11" defaultValue="" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} />
          <div className="label-section">Дата</div>
          <DatePicker
            id="date"
            name="date"
            defaultValue=""
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          />
          <div className="label-section">Оставьте нам сообщение</div>
          <textarea name="text" id="text" type="text" cols={30} rows={10} defaultValue="" onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} /><br /><br />

          <button type="submit" className="xbutton">Отправить</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Transfer;
```

Thanks for any help!)

Comment: Which error? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: The message points this:
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
and this place:
onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-datepicker doesn't fire off the same kind of event that a regular input field would

The react-datepicker onChange function returns a single value - the date selected.

An html input onChange function returns a [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I changed something and it worked.
Not sure that I did it in a better way, but it works.

I declare another function:

```
onChangeDate(date) {
  console.log(date.toISOString());
  this.setState({ startDate: date })
}
```

And use it for the Datepicker component:

```
<DatePicker
  id="date"
  name="date"
  defaultValue=""
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={date => this.onChangeDate(date)}
/>
```

And here, in the array:

```
const data = {
  name: this.state.name,
  email: this.state.email,
  phone: this.state.phone,
  people: this.state.people,
  date: this.state.startDate,
  text: this.state.text
};
```